# Are there security risks storing JavaScript files in localStorage as an offline version of the file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phonegap

I have an app that reads the contents of `example.js` using an AJAX call to `example.php`, then saves `example.js` to a variable, `localStorage.exampleJS`, every time the user opens the app on their phone.
The AJAX call uses the following jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://example.com/example.php",
    success: function(response){
        localStorage.exampleJS = response;
    },
});
```

`example.php` contains the following:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('example.js');
?>
```

In the event that the the user doesn't have an internet connection, I run the offline version using the following jQuery:

```
if(navigator.onLine){
    $("head").append("<script src='https://example.com/example.js'></script>");
}
else{
    $("head").append("<script>" + localStorage.exampleJS + "</script>");    
}
```

I know this could potentially have security risks. Is this a bad practice? Are there security risks doing saving an offline version this way? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You've re-invented how the offline functionality works with progressive web apps. The basic idea is the same - when the app runs online it caches the data from the server (presumably, something that doesn't change a lot but it's useful to always get the latest). Then if the app is running offline, it uses the cached data instead of contacting the server. I suggest looking into PWAs as they have a more robust mechanism of doing that using service workers to handle the caching/retrieval in the background and insulate the app logic from the online/offline logic and also other improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no harm storing file in local-storage, but have to keep following things in your mind.

- File size should not be more than the local-storage size. at any point of time you could utilized full local-storage then you would not be able to store more file.
- Ensure that your all files are uglify and minify, since it will help you in security and space optimization. As uglfy is not human readable so anyone try to read it he is not able to read as file is in uglify form, and minify helps to reduce the file size.